# Updating firestore using previous state

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Is it possible to update firestore using the previous state?

So for example I have an address document which has a `users` field which holds an array of users associated with the address.
whenever I want to add a new user to this array I need the previous array otherwise I will end up overwriting the current data with the new data.

So I end up with something like.

```
   firestore()
    .collection("addresses")
    .doc(addressId)
    .get()
    .then(doc => {
      this.db
        .collection("addresses")
        .doc(addressId)
        .update({
          users: [...doc.data().users, id]
        })
    });
```

Is there a way to access the previous data without having to nest calls?

if not

Is there a better way to manage relationships?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need the previous value to determine the new value, you should use a [transaction](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions#transactions). This is the only way to ensure that different clients aren't accidentally overwriting each other's actions.

Unfortunately transactions also need nested calls, since that is the only way to get the current value, and even have one extra wrapper (for the transaction.

```
var docRef = firestore()
    .collection("addresses")
    .doc(addressId);

return db.runTransaction(function(transaction) {
    // This code may get re-run multiple times if there are conflicts.
    return transaction.get(docRef).then(function(doc) {
        transaction.update(docRef, { users: [...doc.data().users, id ]});
    });
}).then(function() {
    console.log("Transaction successfully committed!");
}).catch(function(error) {
    console.log("Transaction failed: ", error);
});
```

The optimal solution is to use a data structure that doesn't require the current value to add new values. This is one of the reasons [Firebase recommends against using arrays](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2014/04/best-practices-arrays-in-firebase.html): they're inherently hard to scale when multiple users may be adding items to the array. If there is no need for maintaining order between the users, I'd recommend using a set-like structure for the users:

```
users: {
  id1: true,
  id2: true
}
```

This is a collection with two users (`id1` and `id2`). The `true` values are just markers, since you can't have a field without a value.

With this structure, adding a user is as easy as:

```
firestore()
    .collection("addresses")
    .doc(addressId)
    .update({ "users.id3": true })
```

Also see the [Firestore documentation on 
Working with Arrays, Lists, and Sets](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/arrays)

Comment: The transaction api was exactly what I was looking for thanks! I’m going to adopt the second solution and remove the array, I think it will be much easier to manage. Thanks Frank.